# To Verify if Cloudera Hadoop services are running or not in container

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, containers, cloudera-manager, cloudera-quickstart-vm

After starting all the cloudera services in a container through clouera/quickstart image, I need to verify if all services(like HDFS,HBase,Hive etc.) are up or not.. If any service did not come up,try restarting it again or display a message... Can there be a shell-script or java code to verify this ? Need help with the code..

Answer (score 0):

Best way to check is using cloudera Manger web UI, you can see the status of every installed service

You can refer below link for Command line options

http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-6-x/topics/cdh_admin_config.html

Comment: No, actually i need to do some automation where i need to check for the service status, is not started then try restarting it... or atleast display a message to user about which services failed to start...

Answer (score 0):

No, actually i need to do some automation where i need to check for the service status, is not started then try restarting it... or atleast display a message to user about which services failed to start...

Answer (score 0):

I think the Cloudera Manager API is what you're looking for: https://cloudera.github.io/cm_api/